# How to code the last visited date and display it using alert() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, date, time, alert

How can I code the "Last Visited Date" and display it using the `alert()` method?

Here is the JS code:

```js
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
 var d = new Date();
 d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
 var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
 document.cookie = cname+ "=" + cvalue +"; " + expires;
}
function getCookie(cname) {
 var name = cname + "=";
 var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
 for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
  var c = ca[i];
  while (c.charAt (0)==' ') {
   c = c.substring(1);
  }
  if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
   return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
  }
 }
 return "";
}

function checkCookie(){
 var username = getCookie("username");
 if (username != null && username != "")
 {
  alert("Welcome again " + username);
 }
 else
 {
  username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
  if (username != null && username != "")
  {
   setCookie("username",username,365);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: It is recommended to use *toUTCString* rather than *toGMTString*, which is retained for compatibility with old code. You have *set* and *getCookie* functions along with an example of how to use them. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can store anything including dates,boolean flags and objects in your  cookie if you first encode your stuff in JSON.When you want to read just decode it using `parse()` wiz. inverse of `stringify()`.Below is an example I created from your code in my free-time

```
 function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  cvalue = JSON.stringify({username:cvalue,visited:true,visitedOn:d.getTime()});
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = cname+ "=" + cvalue +"; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt (0)==' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        var c = c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        return JSON.parse(c);

    }
  }
  return "";
}

function checkCookie(){
  var user = getCookie("username");

  if (user.visited)
  {
    alert("Welcome again " + user.username + " you visited here on " +  new Date(user.visitedOn).toTimeString() );
    setCookie("username",user.username,365); //update cookie for correct last arrived time
  }
  else
  {
    username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
    if (username != null && username != "")
    {
        setCookie("username",username,365);

    }
  }
}

checkCookie();
```

Comment: I tried to run it, but it doesn't show any alert box. What should I do next? Sorry for having too much questions. I am just a beginner in using Javascript.

Comment: You need to first clear all your cookie (to clear old cookie with same name : username ) and then run the page again

Answer (score 0):

just use localStorage API. http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

all basic API:

```
localStorage.setItem('foo', 'value'); // set/update data
localStorage.getItem('foo'); // returns 'value' or null if not available
localStorage.removeItem('foo'); // removes value from storage
```

And for date management, use momentjs.com

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/

have fun.